# 403 forbidden when Client Cert not in Trusted Root

Tags: c#, azure, ssl-certificate

We use third party which provides for us two certicficates: one Certificate with public key and private key and other only with public key which signes first one.

Every request should be with first public/private key cert:

```
if (ClientCertificate != null)
{
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(ClientCertificate);
}
```

In third party doc discrabed that we should put second cert (with public key) to Trusted Root. And all is good works in this case.

But if second cert is not in Trusted Root (only in Personal) **third party server (based on IIS) returns**

```
HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden
The page you are attempting to access requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client certificate that the Web server recognizes.
```

How we can avoid placing second cert to Trusted Root? We have production in Azure which don't provide Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

May be is difference exist for .Net HttpWebRequest when cert from Personal/Trusted Root is putted during construct request?

Comment: What did you change/set on Azure to instruct the servers to expect/require client certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Purchasing your certificate from a vendor already in everyone's trusted root would resolve this issue. These charge more money, but they can because they are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

We use Azure Web App for our production. Azure Support answered that no any solution exist for placing client cert to Trusted Root. May be in future. As workaround we implemented proxy service which works on Virtual Machine and proxy every requests to Third Party